# How to get current logged in user's roleID in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

As every one knows we can get login `UserId` and `UserName` by

```
string curentUser = User.Identity.GetUserId();
string currentUserName = User.Identity.GetUserName();
```

But how to get current user's `roleId`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the roles the member has like this:

```
using System.Web.Security;    
string[] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(User.Identity.Name);
```

A user can have multiple roles so the type of return value is `string[]`.

**UPDATED**
In ASP.NET Identity 2.0, you can enable `RoleManager` as the following example:

**Models/IdentityModels.cs**

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
}
```

**App_Start/IdentityConfig.cs**

```
public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<ApplicationRole, string>
{
    public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<ApplicationRole, string> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }
    public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        var dbContext = context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>();
        var roleStore = new RoleStore<ApplicationRole>(dbContext);
        var manager = new ApplicationRoleManager(roleStore);

        // Add some roles (e.g. "Administrator") if needed
        if (!manager.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "Administrator"))
        {
            manager.Create(new ApplicationRole
            {
                Name = "Administrator"
            });
        }
        return manager;
    }
}
```

**App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs**

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager≥(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

        // Add this line
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
    }
}
```

**Controllers/AccountController.cs**

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager; 
    private ApplicationRoleManager _roleManager;

    public AccountController()
    {
    }

    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationRoleManager roleManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        RoleManager = roleManager;
        SignInManager = signInManager;
    }

    public ApplicationRoleManager RoleManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _roleManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _roleManager = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can get roles from `UserId` in `Account` controller.

```
var roles = UserManager.GetRoles(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

Comment: Thank you. But when i run this code it takes so long time to execute and then through this error.'{"Unable to connect to SQL Server database."}'

Comment: @user3057643 Could you try `Roles.GetRolesForUser(User.Identity.Name);`?

Comment: @user3057643 I think Role Manager is not enabled in your web.config. Refer (msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647401.aspx). However, since you are using MVC5, I've updated my answer how to use RoleManager in ASP.NET Identiry2.0 (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/03/20/test-announcing-rtm-of-asp-net-identity-2-0-0.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

In Identity you could use `UserManager` to access each users roles as well. Since roles already have been implemented therefor you don't need any extra configuration. So consider this example:

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    userManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

    // return a list of current user's roleIDs
    var roles = userManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId()).Roles.Select(r => r.RoleId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc namespace provides public property User of ClaimsPrincipal type which hold the information of current logged in user , to get current role id
ClaimsPrincipal class have static method FindFirstValue you can use that e.g.
string User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Role);

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.